# Does "Do we still have to meet tomorrow?" sounds reluctant?

Tags: perfect-constructions, future

When somebody asks "Do we still have to meet tomorrow?" when we had an agreement to meet tomorrow, does it show that the speaker is reluctant to meet?

Answer (score 2):

Probably.  The use of "have to meet" suggests that they consider this to be an obligation, not a choice. They are asking if the obligation still exists, so you can infer that if it doesn't exist, they would choose not to meet.